# semantic-release with jenkins don't recognize 'origin/master' as valid branch

Tags: javascript, jenkins, semantic-release

I'm trying to create package with semantic-release and jenkins, but i'm getting de following error

```
2022-01-11T15:53:59.089Z semantic-release:get-tags found tags for branch master: [ { gitTag: 'v0.1.1-0', version: '0.1.1-0', channels: [ null ] } ]
2022-01-11T15:53:59.095Z semantic-release:get-tags found tags for branch next: []
2022-01-11T15:53:59.104Z semantic-release:get-tags found tags for branch develop: []
2022-01-11T15:53:59.111Z semantic-release:get-tags found tags for branch beta: []
[12:53:59 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  This test run was triggered on the branch origin/master, while semantic-release is configured to only publish from master, next, develop, beta, therefore a new version won’t be published.
```

apparently the semantic-release differentiates `master` with `origin/master`

following my `git branch -a`

```
  beta
  develop
* master
  next
  remotes/origin/beta
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/next
```

my `releaserc`

```
{
  "branches": [
    "master",
    "next",
    {
      "name": "develop",
      "prerelease": true
    },
    {
      "name": "beta",
      "prerelease": true
    }
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    [
      "@semantic-release/changelog",
      {
        "changelogFile": "CHANGELOG.md"
      }
    ],
        "@semantic-release/npm",
    [
      "@semantic-release/git",
      {
        "assets": [
                    "package.json",
                    "CHANGELOG.md"
        ],
        "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

my commands

```
sh'''
    export GIT_CREDENTIALS=$USERNAME:$PASSWORD
    git checkout master
    yarn dev-install
    yarn build
    yarn semantic-release --debug
'''
```

Does anyone have any idea what it would be like?

Tks

Comment: Hi! Did you end up finding the solution to your problem?

Comment: what's your pipeline setup?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing the following:

Setting my environment variable

```
GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH = 'master'
```